# Angular 5 HttpClient response headers does not contain custom headers

Tags: node.js, angular, angular4-httpclient

I have API made in Nodejs, after login i send the auth-token (`x-auth` header) in the response on successful login.

When i hit the webservice from postman i am able to see the `x-auth` header but not in Angular 4

I am using HttpClient , not Http.

```
createClient(client:Client){
    return this.http.post(
      Config.baseUrl+'/client/login',client,{observe:'response'});
}
```

Then in my componenet

```
this.userService.createClient(this.signupForm.value).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.clientCreatedSuccessfully = true;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.headers.getAll('x-auth'));
    },(error)=>{
      this.clientExist = true;
      console.log(error);
    })
```

the `data.headers.getAll('x-auth')` returns Null.

Comment: If you're making requests to a third-party Origin, it might be CORS.  The response will need to whitelist custom headers with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Answer (score 7):

Finally got it , it was not a issue with Angular , but with my Node app

Had to add middleware to expose the headers to the client.

```
res.header("access-control-expose-headers",
    ",x-auth"
    +",Content-Length"
);
```

Comment: Hey just as a sidenote -- if you start to run into issues with your Angular app not properly sending headers, you may need to use `withCredentials` `this.http.get(<API_HOST>, {withCredentials: true});` 

This may or may not be helpful in your case but just in case it saves you a bunch of time I put it here

Comment: Took 3 hours to find out this solution